# What is x-plate-ohms on touch?

Tags: touchscreen, touch-panel

I am using tsc2007 on linux.
The linux kernel has the following configuration to use tsc2007.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/input/touchscreen/tsc2007.txt

```
Required properties:
- compatible: must be "ti,tsc2007".
- reg: I2C address of the chip.
- ti,x-plate-ohms: X-plate resistance in ohms.
...
...
...
        tsc2007@49 {
            compatible = "ti,tsc2007";
            reg = <0x49>;
            interrupt-parent = <&gpio4>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x8>;
            gpios = <&gpio4 0 0>;
            ti,x-plate-ohms = <180>;
        };
```

What does `x-plate-ohms` mean?
Is the value dependent on the hardware?
How should `x-plate-ohms` be measured?

Comment: With a dmm that measures resistance.

Comment: @SolarMike
I have a dmm.
But I do not know what x-plate-ohms is.

Comment: You do show the answer "- ti,x-plate-ohms: X-plate resistance in ohms." ie the resistance of the plate for the x-direction in ohms.